# Python issues on character encoding

Tags: python, character-encoding

I'm working on a program that need to take two files and merge them and write the union file as a new one. The problem is that the output file contains chars like this `\xf0` or if i change some of the encodings the result is something like that `\u0028`. The input file are codificated in utf8. How can i print on the output file chars like `"è"` or `"ò"` and `"-"`

I have done this code:

```
import codecs
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


goldstandard = "..\\files\file1.csv"
tweets = "..\\files\\file2.csv"

with codecs.open(tweets, "r", encoding="utf8") as t:
    tFile = pd.read_csv(t, delimiter="\t",
                        names=['ID', 'Tweet'],
                        quoting=3)

IDs = tFile['ID']
tweets = tFile['Tweet']

dict = {}
for i in range(len(IDs)):
    dict[np.int64(IDs[i])] = [str(tweets[i])]


with codecs.open(goldstandard, "r", encoding="utf8") as gs:
    for line in gs:
        columns = line.split("\t")
        index = np.int64(columns[0])
        rowValue = dict[index]
        rowValue.append([columns[1], columns[2], columns[3], columns[5]])
        dict[index] = rowValue

import pprint
pprint.pprint(dict)
ndic = pprint.pformat(dict, indent=4)
f = codecs.open("out.csv", "w", "utf8")
f.write(ndic)
f.close()
```

and this is example of the outputs

```
   desired: Beyoncè
   obtained: Beyonc\xe9
```

Comment: Why are you pretty-printing? That produces *representations*, and string representations produce `\xhh` escape sequences (literally 4 characters, two of which are hex) for any non-printable or non-ASCII codepoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are producing *Python string literals*, here:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(dict)
ndic = pprint.pformat(dict, indent=4)
```

Pretty-printing is useful for producing debugging output; objects are passed through `repr()` to make non-printable and non-ASCII characters easily distinguishable and reproducible:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> value = u'Beyonc\xe9'
>>> value
u'Beyonc\xe9'
>>> print value
Beyoncé
>>> pprint.pprint(value)
u'Beyonc\xe9'
```

The `é` character is in the Latin-1 range, outside of the ASCII range, so it is represented with syntax that produces the same value again when used in Python code.

Don't use `pprint` if you want to write out actual string values to the output file. You'll have to do your own formatting in that case.

Moreover, the pandas dataframe will hold *bytestrings*, not `unicode` objects, so you still have undecoded UTF-8 data at that point.

Personally, I'd not even bother using pandas here; you appear to want to write *CSV* data, so I've simplified your code to use the `csv` module instead, and I'm not actually bothering to decode the UTF-8 here (this is safe for this case as both input and output is entirely in UTF-8):

```
import csv

tweets = {}
with open(tweets, "rb") as t:
    reader = csv.reader(t, delimiter='\t')
    for id_, tweet in reader:
        tweets[id_] = tweet

with open(goldstandard, "rb") as gs, open("out.csv", 'wb') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(gs, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.reader(outf, delimiter='\t')
    for columns in reader:
        index = columns[0]
        writer.writerow([tweets[index]] + columns[1:4] + [columns[5])
```

Note that you really want to avoid using `dict` as a variable name; it masks the built-in type, I used `tweets` instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, i noticed that now with the json.dump the output is 

\\u201c

For printing i changed he code to:

json.dump(unicode(dict), json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

without unicode it wont print (error)

Comment: @ForceITA: `unicode(dict)` will convert your whole dictionary to a single `unicode()` object by calling `repr()` on the object *first*. You really don't want that.  I see the problem now, you are using `index = np.int64(columns[0])` as the dictionary key, and JSON requires that you use strings for keys instead.

Comment: @ForceITA: updated the code to convert all keys to strings first.

Comment: @ForceITA: also, you are converting all your tweets to `str()` earlier on which can produce similar issues; what format is that column in?

Comment: Now i'm watching the dict as i populate it, and in the memoy i had \u201c

So i think it's  a problem somewhere before printing.
I will try to change keys

Comment: @ForceITA: since you did not provide any input samples, actual output produced for those samples nor expected output to go with all that, I have to do a lot of guessing here; there appear to be multiple issues in the code here.

Comment: Looking to notepad++ it says -  UNIX | UTF-8.

I can't provide an input, i have not the rights to upload.

Honestly now i'm just trying to guess, i can't figure out whats the problem.

Comment: @ForceITA: re-reading your question once more I noticed that your output file uses the extension `.csv`. I've re-written my answer to actually write out CSV data, watching tweets from the input to tweets from the `goldstandard` file.

Comment: @ForceITA: we don't need the *actual* data, we need *representative* data. So if you have a few sample lines with made-up data that's fine, as long as it produces the same problem you see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110606/discussion-between-martijn-pieters-and-forceita).